# Will managed objects without roots be destroyed during next GC run?

Tags: .net, debugging, memory, windbg

I'm trying to analyze dump of the .NET web application under heavy load.

Through WinDbg I see that my GC heap is around 1GB.
dumpheap shows that it filled with similar managed objects, gcroot for which return:

`Found 0 unique roots`

My question is: Can I be sure that Garbage Collector will destroy objects without roots on the next run or is it a sign of a memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I be sure that Garbage Collector will destroy objects without roots on the next run?

No. The garbage collector can run for different [generations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#generations): 0, 1 and 2. The object will only be garbage collected when it's in the same or lower generation the GC runs for:

- A gen 0 object will always be collected.
- A gen 1 object will be collected during a gen 1 and gen 2 run.
- A gen 2 object will only be collected on a gen 2 run

Also, if the object has a finalizer, it may run 1 GC later, because the finalizer must be run first. But in this case, the object should be rooted to the finalize queue.

> Is it a sign of a memory leak?

No. Especially if you have immutable objects like `string`, it's normal that they will come and go (many of them likely in gen 0).